# gnuplot, here-documents, and command line arguments

Tags: bash, here-document, gnuplot

Can I use a here document to pass a gnuplot script to gnuplot and also have commandline line arguments passed to gnuplot?

In my bash file, I would normally write:

```
#!/bin/bash
#set up code in here...
gnuplot -c script.gp $first $second
```

But I want to have everything in one bash file, so I've done

```
#!/bin/bash
#set up code in here...
gnuplot -c <<- EOF
do for [j=0:ARG1] {
   do for [i=4:ARG2] {
      plot '${data}' index j using 2:i with lp
   }
}
EOF $first $second
```

but I get the infamous `warning: here-document at line 87 delimited by end-of-file (wanted`EOF')`` error. `$data`, `$first`, and `$second` are defined earlier in the bash script.

If I put the command line arguments on the next line, to leave the EOF alone, I get command not found errors associated with the value of `$first`.

My here document is indented only with tabs. There is no trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

This is one solution: get rid of the arguments, and do the replacement manually.

```
#!/bin/bash
#set up code in here...
gnuplot <<- EOF
do for [j=0:${first}] {
   do for [i=4:${second}] {
      plot '${data}' index j using 2:i with lp
   }
}
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
gnuplot -c /dev/stdin "$first" "$second" <<-EOF
do for [j=0:ARG1] {
   do for [i=4:ARG2] {
      plot '${data}' index j using 2:i with lp
   }
}
EOF
```

Gnuplot complains

```
line 4: No previous filename
```

but then I get the same error when using a script file, so it's probably something to do with the code being incomplete.